# Path SDK for Unity

Tags: android, sdk, unity-game-engine

Maybe a simple question but i can't seem to get it fixed.

- I want to Build my Application (for android)
- After i connected the SDK and JDK path's i press build
- The following message pops up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

fixed it by downgrading the sdk tools.

1. Delete android sdk "tools" folder
   : [Android SDK root]/tools -> tools
2. Download SDK Tools:
   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip
3. Extract the folder to Android SDK root
4. Build your project

Answer (score 0):

found it:

Download tools r25.2.5
Google

Change your tools folder to toolsXXXX (because you need it for Android studio)
unzip the tools r25.2.5 in the SDK location

Works fine now. probably something with an update...